# Adapted and progressive processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Could you please help me proving rigorously the following fact from Mayer's book:

(a) if $X_t$ is a process adapted with respect to filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$  is progressively measurable with respect to $\{\mathcal{F}_{t+\varepsilon}\}_{t\ge 0}$. Then $X_t$ is progressively measurable wrt $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$.

(b) if the adaptation hypothesis is omitted, then $X_t$ is progressively measurable only wrt $\{\mathcal{F}_{t+}\}_{t\ge 0}$.

Let me remind the definition:

Real-valued process $X_t, t\ge 0$ (given on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is called progressively measurable with respect family $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ if for every $t\ge 0$ the mapping $(s, \omega)\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ from $[0,t]\times \Omega$ into $(R, \mathcal{B}(R))$ is measurable wrt product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$

Answer (score -1):

(a) For any fixed $t$, we know from the condition that

$X\mid_{[0,t-\frac{1}{N}]\times \Omega} \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$

is $\mathcal B([0 ,\ \  t-\frac{1}{N}]) \times \mathcal F_t$ measurable, therefore, for any $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$,

$(X\mid_{[0,t)\times \Omega})^{-1}(A)= \mathop{\cup}_{N}\left ((X\mid_{[0,t-\frac{1}{N}]\times \Omega})^{-1}(A) \right)$, which is $\mathcal B([0 ,\ \  t) \times \mathcal F_t$ measurable.

Since $(X\mid_{[0,t]\times \Omega})^{-1}(A) = (X\mid_{[0,t)\times \Omega})^{-1}(A)\mathop{\cup} (t, X_t^{-1}(A)) $. Given that $X_t$ is adapted to $\mathcal F_t$, we conclude that $(X\mid_{[0,t]\times \Omega})^{-1}(A)$ is $\mathcal B([0 ,\ \  t] \times \mathcal F_t$ measurable.

(b) Perhaps I missed something, but this seems to be straightforward.

Comment: Guess I deserve the negative vote for some notation problem. I should have made it clear that, for any $A\subset B$,  I consider $A\times \Omega$ a subset of $B\times \Omega$ by natural embedding.  Any constructive criticisms are welcome.